# Bitcode error occurs during the complication of Bluemix Cordova application for iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, ibm-cloud

When I attempt to deploy a Bluemix Cordova application for iOS, I encounter the following Bitcode compilation error:

```
 ld: 'BluemixData/Plugins/com.ibm.mobile.cordova.ibmbluemix/IBMBluemix.framework/
IBMBluemix(IBMBluemix.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode 
enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or 
disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 ** BUILD FAILED **


 The following build commands failed:
     Ld build/device/BluemixData.app/BluemixData normal armv7
```

I have disabled the Bitcode in the `.xcodeproj` file and I am still seeing the same problem. The project compiles and deploys correctly for Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your res folder from your project, add these folders:

> res -> native -> ios -> cordova

[image]

In the cordova folder add a file named `build.xcconfig`, with this line:

```
ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
```

It should prevent this error from showing up. Don't forget to remove and add the ios platform, to make sure the changes are picked up. It worked for me.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: I tought that visual studio was just an IDE to make cordova development easy, i had no idea these folder structures are unique to it. So this is no possibility for a bluemix user?

Comment: I don't know how bluemix works, I though it was for online webservices and didn't have IDE. On a regular cordova project, the build.xcconfig is on platforms/ios/cordova